# How to detect if face unlock is enabled in ICS?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I need to be able to detect whether the user has face unlock enabled in ICS (android 4.0). Is there any way to do it?

I am able to detect if a lock pattern is enabled like this:

Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED)

But there does not appear to be an equivalent setting for face unlock.

Thanks.

Comment: i did not find a solution, but i did end up using logcat to watch for the face unlock setup activity being launched. my app needs to warn the user not to use face unlock, so this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on the same issue.   This is the only solution I've come across, but it required Device Administration to be enabled for your app.

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), WrDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
dpm.setPasswordQuality(component, DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_BIOMETRIC_WEAK); 
result = (dpm.isActivePasswordSufficient() == true);
dpm.setPasswordQuality(component,  DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: this actually doesn't work for me. it gives a false positive if you have a pin or password and face unlock is not enabled. from the android docs: "Quality constants are ordered so that higher values are more restrictive". PASSWORD_QUALITY_BIOMETRIC_WEAK is the second lowest numbered constant (32768), just above PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED (0) and just below PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING (65536). so any existing password quality that is more restrictive than PASSWORD_QUALITY_BIOMETRIC_WEAK, which is nearly all of them, will cause isActivePasswordSufficient() to return true.